# Need to know how to select customer names where their purchase price is greater than 100

Tags: mysql, sql, sum, where-clause, having

i have a sql homework. i Have built a small database with 3 tables(in images).I need to select customer names that have purchased for more than 100 within last month.All purchases are separated.

I tried using using SUM

```
SELECT  customer.CustomerName
FROM customer INNER JOIN
     sales
     ON customer.id=sales.CustomerId
HAVING SUM(sales.SalesPrice > 100)
```

In my database there are customers that the sum of Sales price is greteater than 0 but SQL return blank output[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TOxj1.png)

Comment: You are missing `GROUP BY`.

Comment: Thank you for the fast response but no luck. added GROUP BY customer.id ASC but get this message #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY customer.id LIMIT 0, 25' at line 1

Comment: Maybe have a read of the manual when using unfamiliar syntax.

Comment: ran this SELECT customer.CustomerName FROM customer INNER JOIN sales ON customer.id=sales.CustomerId GROUP BY customer.CustomerName HAVING SUM(sales.SalesPrice > 100) but i still received blank output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT customer.customerName FROM customer 
INNER JOIN sales ON customer.id = sales.customerId
GROUP BY customerName
HAVING SUM(sales.SalesPrice) > 100;
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct syntax looks like this:

```
SELECT c.CustomerName
FROM customer c INNER JOIN
     sales s
     ON c.id = s.CustomerId
GROUP BY c.id, c.CustomerName
HAVING SUM(s.SalesPrice) > 100;
```

Comment: @SimasKasparaitis . . . Is there a reason you unaccepted this answer?

Comment: both answers are good. I would accept them both :)) but gautam has less reputation so i decided to give this to him

Answer (score 0):

The second part of this task needs me to write a query that return an item name that has the most transaction count. I need to know which `ItemId.Sales` has the most values. Currently I have this code

```
SELECT ItemName 
FROM item 
INNER JOIN sales ON item.id = sales.ItemID
```

but I need to know how to count those `ItemID`'s and which `ID` has the biggest count

Answer (score 0):

> I need to select customer names that have purchased for more than 100 **within last month**

```
    SELECT C.CustomerName
      FROM customer AS C INNER JOIN sales AS S ON C.id = S.CustomerId
     WHERE S.SalesDate >= '20190701' AND S.SalesDate < '20190801' --within last month
  GROUP BY C.CustomerName
    HAVING SUM(S.SalesPrice) > 100   --Sum of purchases greater than 100
```

This sort of requires looking at the picture link, which should be included as part of the question, not as a link.  For example, the link could expire or the link could be blocked by an organization's firewall.